# Will the ffmpeg community add FTL (Mixer) support to ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Maybe somewhere here has some insight into the ffmpeg dev community, maybe this question is better on Stack Exchange, but it seems like the ftl-sdk has been out for a bit, but I don't see any signs its being added to ffmpeg?

Will ffmpeg be able to stream FTL (Faster Then Light) to Mixer?

Comment: I;ve seen no serious discussion (or request) for it being added. Post an enhancement ticket on trac.ffmpeg.org, if you like. Appears to be WebRTC-derived.